# Reordering the contents of a file using tcl

Tags: tcl

I’m a newbie to Tcl and code writing in general. I have what seems like a simple coding issue that I have about 10 hrs into that I can’t seem to resolve.
I have a file that contains a list of nets clk123, n789, clk456, n246…. I need to reorder the list so that the clk* nets appear first when outputted. I can read the files in question and output the contents to the monitor or a file. But, I’m not able to find a way to reorder the list. I’ve spent so much time researching this that I’m now completely confused. Can someone offer a suggestion?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Please provide a sample input file and the output you wish to see. I wonder if `set new_order [exec sort $filename]` will meet your goal.

Answer (score 1):

If there's just `clk*` and `n*` nets, a simple sort should be sufficient:

```
package require fileutil

proc sort data {
    set lines [split $data \n]
    set lines [lsort $lines]
    join $lines \n
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace thefile.txt sort
```

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)